# Android Emulator: How to not proxy 10.0.2.2 when proxy server is setup?

Tags: android, proxy, emulation, loopback

While developing on my emulator, I want to hit a server on my local machine, when I connect to 10.0.2.2, but I also want to use my proxy server to get out to the Internet for other connections.  Is there a way to do this without running my own proxy server?  It's annoying that there's no way to have a list of excluded proxy hosts.  Or maybe someone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a proxy server ([WireMock](http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/)) in order to receive *all* the traffic, and then with mappings I can decide where to proxy the request to.  Either a service running locally, or a service that runs somewhere else.  It's nice that WireMock can also use another proxy server to get the request to the final destination.

I can differentiate the different proxied endpoints using different mappings with different ports.  If I want to use a real device I can use 'adb reverse' to send the request over USB even.